# Solve the equation given below...

Tags: trigonometry, absolute-value

I have such an exercise:

$$\color{teal}{{|x|\over{x}}\sin^2x-\cos|x|\cos x=1} $$
What I did is so:

If  $x\ge 0$ then we have:

$$\sin^2x-\cos^2x=1$$

$$\sin^2x=1$$

So: $$\sin x=1$$  or $$\sin x=-1$$

This means that we have two sets of solutions:
$\color{blue}{x={\pi\over2}+2\pi k}$   and $\color{blue}{x={3\pi \over 2}+2\pi k}$

The problem is I do not know what solutions to choose from the set I presented above, knowing that $x\ge0$.

Now, it's your turn if you please. What values should be choosen? My opinion is that $k\ge 0$ Thank you very much!:)

Comment: Well, you can simplify a bit since $\;\cos x=\cos(-x)=\cos|x|\;$ ...

Comment: Thank you I haven't seen this , but as the question remains the same can you explain me this?

Comment: What do you mean "what solutions to choose?" You've described all the positive solutions. You could simplify your answer as one equation $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k$.

Comment: how did you get rid of the $cos^2$ ?

Comment: I'm assuming, since $\sin^2x\leq 1$ and $\cos^2\geq 0$ then $\sin^2x-\cos^2x=1$ only when $\sin^2=1$ and $\cos^2=0$, for the step where you conclude $\sin^2 x=1$? That step is odd.

Comment: Sorry I was blind while solving this equation, and have got a problem  like a child. THank you for you suggestion and criticism :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

$$x\ge 0\implies \sin^2x-\cos^2x=-\cos2x=1\iff \cos 2x=-\frac12\iff\ldots$$

$$x<0\implies -\sin^2x-\cos^2x=-(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)=-1\neq1\;\ldots$$

Comment: @JohnG. , you're welcome...though somebody didn't like this answer. Oh, well...

Comment: Your answer is the best and the unique in the universe of this page:)

Comment: For some that's not enough, @JohnG....:)

Comment: For $$x\ge 0\$$ your top line should read $cos2x=-1$ surely?

Comment: @GuyCorrigall, that's what it is written there: $$-\cos 2x=1\iff \cos 2x = -1\;\;\ldots$$